# how to test my app with google analytic in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics

I am integrating Google analytics to my ios app.Is there any Google Analytics testing/sandbox environment for testing my app before putting it to live system?

Comment: no sandbox mode for GA, use 2 keys one is original and another one is duplicate , in your testing mode use duplicate key , when u r pushing the live use live key

Comment: Thanks. But how to create duplicate key?

Comment: simple, create the another one key

Comment: i did last 3 projects just like, k  welcome my friend,if u need andy assistance i surly hope with u

Comment: duplicate key will show my statistics before my app got released?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66473/discussion-between-madhumitha-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could enable "dryrun" and verbose logging with:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance] setDryRun:YES];
[[GAI sharedInstance].logger setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
```

Google Analytics will behave as it would normally except it will not upload any data.

Analytics dev guide has [section about testing](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/advanced#testing) describing it in more details.